# Attempting Windows deployment - .exe file not opening with no error messages

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, qml

I have been attempting to deploy my app to windows (a laptop without QT installed) and I am assuming I have a dependency issue, but I am getting no error messages.

Currently using: C:\Qt\5.12.6\mingw73_64

My app runs fine in QtCreator, and I have used windeployqt (with adding the qmldir as well), which works fine initially. However, I change my C:\Qt folder to C:\QtHidden (I read somewhere that this imitates not having QT installed) and my .exe file does not load. I can click on it, but no error message comes up, my mouse cursor changes to a loading cursor for a few moments, and then nothing happens. Does anyone know of a way I can log what is happening so I can try to fix it?

I also tried following https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows 'initial deployment' instructions where I put every .dll file from /bin, and every folder from plugins and qml. The same no error and no opening problem occurs and I'm not sure what else I can do.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that your application based on QML UI, is that right? Then QML engine can't load your root object for some reason. In that case you won't get any errors. Unless you alter your main.cpp code to open QMessageBox in case root element cannot be loaded.

Comment: I implemented custom logger to file to diagnose such issues. I recommend you to do the same

Comment: Also, does it have any custom QML plugin extensions? That could be a reason too. Qt 5.12.6 doesn't deploy .dll's for such extensions automatically. I have a project that includes QML plugin extension that compiles .dll and copies it to the target folder. windeployqt of 5.12.6 can't find it on its own and transfer to your target folder.

Comment: Check this article https://evileg.com/en/post/154/ . I used something same to see QML errors in a text file while testing application on another machine without any pre-installed Qt libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement custom message logger. I used this code once (this one is in my actuall app and pretty generic). It can log QML errors too:

```
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <iostream>

QUrl logFileUrl;
bool logToFile=true;
int appLogLevel=3;

void logger(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg){
    bool writeLogLine = false;
    QString line;
    QString msgType;
    QString time = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss.zzz");
    switch (type) {
    case QtInfoMsg:{
        msgType = "Info";
        break;
    }
    case QtDebugMsg:{
        msgType = "Debug";
        break;
    }
    case QtWarningMsg:{
        msgType = "Warning";
        break;
    }
    case QtCriticalMsg:{
        msgType = "Critical";
        break;
    }
    case QtFatalMsg:{
        msgType = "Fatal";
        abort();
    }
    }
    line = QString("[%1] <%2> %3 (%4) | %5:%6 (%7) '%8'")
            .arg(time)
            .arg(static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(QThread::currentThreadId())))
            .arg(msgType)
            .arg(context.category)
            .arg(context.file)
            .arg(context.line)
            .arg(context.function)
            .arg(msg);
    if (!logToFile){
        writeLogLine = false;
        std::cout << line.toStdString() << std::endl;
    } else {
        switch (appLogLevel){
        case 0:{
            writeLogLine = false;
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            if (type == QtFatalMsg)
                writeLogLine = true;
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            if (type == QtCriticalMsg || type == QtFatalMsg)
                writeLogLine = true;
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            if (type != QtInfoMsg && type != QtDebugMsg)
                writeLogLine = true;
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            if (type != QtDebugMsg)
                writeLogLine = true;
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
            writeLogLine = true;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    if (writeLogLine){
        QFile logFile(logFileUrl.toLocalFile());
        if (logFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)) {
            QTextStream ts(&logFile);
            ts << line << endl;
            logFile.close();
        } else {
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("WARNING");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
            msgBox.setText(logFile.errorString());
            msgBox.setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
            msgBox.exec();
        }
    }
}
```

And the installer it using `qInstallMessageHandler`:

```
qInstallMessageHandler(logger);
```

Check documentation here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler

P.S. - this code also displays all message in your `QtCreator` instance when running from there.

Comment: Thanks, user3417815! The logger and docs you sent me to were just what I needed. It ended up being a SQLite error - but pretty easy to solve once I could see what the error was!